# Using POST for flight API

Tags: ios, objective-c, post

I have been trying to implement the Wego flights API from http://support.wan.travel/hc/en-us/articles/200191669 which uses HTTP POST requests. I've only really ever used GET requests, so I did some reading on POST and so far I have not been able to find a way to post a request with a dictionary of flight data (in objective-c) as shown in the link above:

```
POST api.wego.com/flights/api/k/2/searches

{
  "trips": [
    {
      "departure_code": "SYD",
      "arrival_code": "LON",
      "outbound_date": "2014-01-24",
      "inbound_date": "2014-01-29"
    }
  ],
  "adults_count": 1
}
```

Do I have to create the NSDictionary myself and then (assign?) it to the request, or is there a way to format the dictionary into a string? Thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create the POST data as follows:

```
NSDictionary *trips = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                       @"SYD", @"departure_code",
                       @"LON", @"arrival_code",
                       @"2014-01-24", @"outbound_date",
                       @"2014-01-29", @"inbound_date",
                       nil];
NSDictionary *postDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      trips, @"trips",
                      @"1", @"adults_count",
                      nil];

NSError *jsonError = nil;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:postDict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&jsonError];
```

And then make the POST request:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://api.wego.com/flights/api/k/2/searches"];
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:15];
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

const char *parameters = [jsonData bytes];
NSData *postData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:parameters length:strlen(parameters)];
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *requestError = nil;
NSData * data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:&requestError];
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]]);
```